# Java script unwanted reload of page after completing execution

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on client side rendering. I have a input tag where i put a number and click button. Onclick of button it should add more input tags to my page .But the problem is it adds given number of inputs and reset page for no reason.

Please explain me why it is reseting page ?

```
<HTML>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
//for converting document.getelementbyid() to _()
<body>
    <div id="form_place">
    <form>
        <input name="nos" id='nos' type="text">
        <button onclick="addnos()">Enter</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
<SCRIPT>
function addnos(){

    var nos =  _('nos').value;
    for (i=0;i < nos;i++){

    manddy = document.createElement('INPUT');
    manddy.setAttribute("id", 'name'+i+1);
    _('form_place').appendChild(manddy);

    }                           
}    
    </SCRIPT>

</HTML>
```

Comment: You put your controls inside Form element that is used to post on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't forget the default behavior of a button in a form is submit. That will be triggering a reload. Change your code to this:

```
<HTML>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
//for converting document.getelementbyid() to _()
<body>
    <div id="form_place">
    <form>
        <input name="nos" id='nos' type="text">
        <button type="button" onclick="addnos()">Enter</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
<SCRIPT>
function addnos(){

    var nos =  _('nos').value;
    for (i=0;i < nos;i++){

    manddy = document.createElement('INPUT');
    manddy.setAttribute("id", 'name'+i+1);
    _('form_place').appendChild(manddy);

    }                           
}    
    </SCRIPT>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Your onclick event act like ah form submit.
>
> 2.No return statement is there.so the page was reload.
>
> 3.If you apply within action of form `form action="some.php"` the page redirect with that page like `http://firsthtml/some.php`
>
> 4.[More reference and demo of from submit](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp)
>
> 5.So apply with return false statement .Its will prevent your page resting.And apply click function into form submit see the below code

```
 <HTML>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    //for converting document.getelementbyid() to _()
    <body>
        <div id="form_place">
        <form onsubmit="return addnos()"> <!--return with function-->
            <input name="nos" id='nos' type="text">
            <button  >Enter</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <SCRIPT>
    function addnos(){

        var nos =  _('nos').value;
        for (i=0;i < nos;i++){

        manddy = document.createElement('INPUT');
        manddy.setAttribute("id", 'name'+i+1);
        _('form_place').appendChild(manddy);

        }                           
                              return false; //its will prevent page refresh
    }    
        </SCRIPT>

    </HTML>
```

Comment: Actually your method is correct but , I found that if we didn't specified type='button' for a button it acts like a form SUBMIT button . thanks for ur offered help

Answer (score 1):

```
    <HTML>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
//for converting document.getelementbyid() to _()
<body>
    <div id="form_place">
    <form>
        <input name="nos" id='nos' type="text">
        <button onclick="return addnos()">Enter</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
<SCRIPT>
function addnos(){

    var nos =  _('nos').value;
    for (i=0;i < nos;i++){

    manddy = document.createElement('INPUT');
    manddy.setAttribute("id", 'name'+i+1);
    _('form_place').appendChild(manddy);

    }

    return false;
 }    
    </SCRIPT>

</HTML>
```

Change your code like this. This will prevent the default behaviour because, in HTML you call return someFunc() so is going to return whatever the function returns. And the function returns a false! so in the end, it returns false to the onclick method and the default behaviour is prevented while your code is executed.

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Actually your method is correct but , I found that if we didn't specified type='button' for a button it acts like a form SUBMIT button . thanks for ur offered help